# PHP/Parse.com – Does require() not carry over user "Parse\ParseQuery?"

Tags: php, parse-platform

I want to run code from **awesomeQuery.php** on multiple pages, so I use PHP require.

```
<?php require_once("awesomeQuery.php") ?>
```

The **awesomeQuery.php** looks something like this:

```
<?php
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use Parse\ParseQuery;
    [query code here that works]
?>
```

Now here's ***spiffyPage.php***:

```
<?php
    //This line here works beautifully!
    require_once("awesomeQuery.php");

    //If I make a new query code in this file I get the following error:
    //Fatal error: Class 'ParseQuery' not found in /path/spiffyPage.php on line 45
    [some other similar query code]
?>
```

Is there a reason why this new query isn't working? Didn't I already call `use Parse\ParseQuery` from **awesomeQuery.php**? Does it not carry over into ***spiffyPage.php***?

If I call `use Parse\ParseQuery` separately in ***spiffyPage.php***, then the new query code *does* work… but I'd rather not have to call it *every time!*

My guess: All the PHP code in **awesomeQuery.php** gets executed before being pasted into ***spiffyPage.php***, so the code `use Parse\ParseQuery` doesn't get pasted into ***spiffyPage.php***. Is this correct? If so, can I paste code into a file from another file without executing the code first?

Answer (score 1):

the PHP manual clearly says that

> Note:
>   Importing rules are per file basis, meaning included files will NOT inherit the parent file's importing rules.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: Thanks. Is there no way around this? Will I have to import ParseQuery on every file I want to use it in the page itself?